# Add Modify or Delete any row in angular Mat Table , angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using angular 8 for my req which states I have to add/Modify/delete rows in my Table from UI. I am using mat table, at time of adding or deleting or modifying my records are reaching to ts file and updating the DataSource, but after the update it is not reflecting back to my UI. Attaching my UI screenshot for more understanding, I tried refering some of the blogs for guidance but unable to find a fix. Need some help for this.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you will add [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or some snippet of your code it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Asaf thanks for the response, i referred below blog and it worked for me :  https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-operations-using-dialog/#Create_a_new_Angular_Project